# jquery function not taking \" from PHP code

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Hi I am using one custom control by PHP code

```
  $parentLinkCombo = '<select name="ParentComboLink" onchange="changeChildCombo(\"LICENCE\");" id="ParentComboLink" >';
```

I am adding changeChildCombo function for onchange event and pass argument like this but it gives me this error

```
Timestamp: 7/2/2014 5:39:06 PM
Error: SyntaxError: illegal character
Source File: http://amatiacloud.com/intertek/modules/editar_actividades.php?ida=1777
Line: 1, Column: 17
Source Code:
changeChildCombo(\
```

please tell me how to add " under any "

Comment: @AnoopJoshi Sir if this would work then I will not ask question.

Comment: You can use like this '<select name="ParentComboLink" onchange="changeChildCombo(\'LICENCE\');" id="ParentComboLink" >' see the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/J24yN/255/

Comment: @AnoopJoshi Sir you are right but please see my code and question it is PHP code...I am not generating combo from js....

Comment: Does that mean that you can't use the above code in php?

Comment: @AnoopJoshi Yes sir I can't use your code as well as mine in php script and having the same error with your and mine both's code if you want then I can give snapshot of this

Comment: No need bro. Just needed to know(I'm a .net guy though).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to have a `\` character as data in a PHP string, then you need to escape it: `\\`, but that won't help.

`\` is not an escape character in HTML. Use `&quot;` instead of `\"`.

Comment: That's one thing. Another is this string is encapsulated within `''` instead of `""`. Special controls like escaping, `\n` or `\r` doesn't work on single quoted strings.

Comment: @Quentin Thanks ...I wonder this is working so easily ....I faced this problem many times but never think like this 

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to use escaped single quotes in the javascript function, like this:

`$parentLinkCombo = '<select name="ParentComboLink" onchange="changeChildCombo(\'LICENCE\');" id="ParentComboLink" >';`